# Debugger friendly list class

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, list, c#-4.0

The generic list class show lots of more or less useless information in debugger, like `_syncRoot`, `Capacity` and so on. Even the `_items` field is a little bit annoying. 
Is there a way to get debug information that is as smart as usual? Or is something comparable to DebuggerDisplay attribute for build-in classes?

Comment: "Capaceity"? Sorry I'm not familiar with that propeirty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to uncheck this option: Tools | Options | Debugging | General | Show raw structure of objects in variables window.  Once unchecked you will get the visualizer for the `List<>`.

Answer (score 2):

The List<> class already has a visualizer:

[image]

Not sure why you don't see it, you'd have to select the Raw view to see private members.  Which is, well, raw.

Comment: Hmm, ignore the hex view I had active.